# Allow inline chat edit, or better indication that inline is not possible

Tags: feature-request, chat

[image]

I often find attempting to edit my chat message right in the chat itself, and not in the "entry box" at the bottom.

I wish it were possible to either edit the message directly in the chat stream, or that it was made more obvious that it can only be done in the entry box, by better distinguishing it from the message itself.